# Create triggers for calculating sum in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this tables in postgres

```sql
CREATE TABLE voting_option (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  -- SUM of all vote values for this voting option id
  votes_value INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
CREATE TABLE vote (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  voting_option_id INT NOT NULL,
  -- can be positive/negative or 0
  value INT NOT NULL
);
```

I want to create triggers that will automatically update `votes_value` every time I `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` a record to the `vote` table.

Something like this:

For INSERT: `votes_value` += `vote.value`

For DELETE: `votes_value` -= `vote.value`

For UPDATE: `votes_value` = `votes_value` - old `vote.value` + new `vote.value`

Comment: Have you considered using a `view`?

Comment: Here you have the posgres trigger documentaion: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: We won't write the code for you. Please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

As @JimJones noticed, all you need is this simple view. You will have clean insert-only workflow as a bonus too instead of an update workflow in disguise.

```sql
create view voting_option_v as
 select voting_option_id id, sum(value) votes_value
 from vote 
 group by voting_option_id;
```